# FutureBuilder snapshot returning null, possible json parsing failure

Tags: flutter

I am trying to render a list based on an API response. Here is the model :

```
class ProductModel {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  final String nameBn;
  final String price;
  final String priceBn;
  final bool oldPrice;
  final String oldPriceVal;
  final String oldPriceValBn;
  final List<ImageBunny> image;
  final String slug;
  final String shortDescriptionOpt;
  final String shortDescription;
  final String shortDescriptionBn;
  final int maxItem;
  final bool size;
  final List<String> sizeList;
  final bool color;
  final List<String> colorList;
  final bool unit;
  final String unitBn;
  final String unitEn;
  final int ranking;

  ProductModel(
      {this.id,
      this.name,
      this.nameBn,
      this.price,
      this.priceBn,
      this.oldPrice,
      this.oldPriceVal,
      this.oldPriceValBn,
      this.image,
      this.slug,
      this.shortDescriptionOpt,
      this.shortDescription,
      this.shortDescriptionBn,
      this.maxItem,
      this.color,
      this.colorList,
      this.ranking,
      this.size,
      this.sizeList,
      this.unit,
      this.unitBn,
      this.unitEn
      });
}
```

and the listview component:

```
class Products extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return _buildProductsListPage();
  }

  _buildProductsListPage() {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.grey[100],
      child: FutureBuilder<List<ProductModel>>(
        future: _parseProductsFromResponse(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.active:

            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());

            case ConnectionState.none:
              return Center(child: Text("Unable to connect right now"));

            case ConnectionState.done:
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 18,
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  print(index);
                  print(snapshot.data);

                  return ProductComponent(
                      product1: snapshot.data[index - 1],
                      product2: snapshot.data[index],
                    );
                },
              );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }



  Future<dynamic> _getProducts() async {
    var response = await http.get('https://example.com/api/featured/').catchError(
      (error) {
        return false;
      },
    );

    return json.decode(response.body);
  }

  Future<List<ProductModel>> _parseProductsFromResponse() async {
    List<ProductModel> productsList = <ProductModel>[];


    var dataFromResponse = await _getProducts();

    dataFromResponse['results'].forEach(
      (newProduct) {
        //print(newProduct);
        //parse the product's images
        List<ImageBunny> imagesOfProductList = [];
        print("hit 1");

        newProduct["image"].forEach(
          (newImage) {
            print("hit 2");
            imagesOfProductList.add(
              new ImageBunny(
                imageMobileFeatureList: newImage["imageMobileFeatureList"],
                imageMobileProductDetails: newImage["imageMobileProductDetails"],
              ),
            );
          },
        );


        // parse Size List
        List<String> sizeList = [];
        newProduct["size_list"].forEach((value) {
          print("hit 3");
          sizeList.add(value);
        });

        print("hit 4");

        // parse Color List
        List<String> colorList = [];
        newProduct["color_list"].forEach((value) {
          print("hit 5");
          var color = value.toString();
          var colorVal = color.substring(1, color.length);
          colorList.add(colorVal);
        });

        print("hit 6");

        //parse new product's details
        ProductModel product = ProductModel(
          id: int.tryParse(newProduct["id"]),
          name: newProduct["name"].toString(),
          nameBn: newProduct["name_bn"].toString(),
          price: newProduct["price"].toString(),
          priceBn: newProduct["price_bn"].toString(),
          oldPrice: newProduct["old_price"],
          oldPriceVal: newProduct["old_price_val"] != null? newProduct["old_price_val"].toString(): "",
          oldPriceValBn: newProduct["old_price_val_bn"] != null? newProduct["old_price_val_bn"].toString(): "",
          slug: newProduct["slug"].toString(),
          shortDescriptionOpt: newProduct["short_description_opt"],
          shortDescription: newProduct["short_description"].toString(),
          shortDescriptionBn: newProduct["short_description_bn"].toString(),
          maxItem: newProduct["max_item"],
          size: newProduct["size"],
          sizeList: sizeList,
          color: newProduct["color"],
          colorList: colorList,
          unit: newProduct["unit"],
          unitBn: newProduct["unit_bn"] != null? newProduct["unit_bn"].toString() : "",
          unitEn: newProduct["unit_en"] != null? newProduct["unit_en"].toString() : "",
          ranking: newProduct["ranking"],
          image: imagesOfProductList,
        );

        print("hit 7");

        productsList.add(product);
      },
    );

    print(productsList);
    return productsList;
  }
}
```

and the terminal output:

```
I/flutter (14968): hit 1
I/flutter (14968): hit 2
I/flutter (14968): hit 4
I/flutter (14968): hit 6
I/flutter (14968): 0
I/flutter (14968): null
I/flutter (14968): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (14968): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building:
I/flutter (14968): The method '[]' was called on null.
I/flutter (14968): Receiver: null
I/flutter (14968): Tried calling: [](-1)
I/flutter (14968): 
I/flutter (14968): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (14968): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:50:5)
I/flutter (14968): #1      Products._buildProductsListPage.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:eknimishei/partials/products.dart:73:46)
I/flutter (14968): #2      SliverChildBuilderDelegate.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:398:15)
I/flutter (14968): #3      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement._build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1006:67)
I/flutter (14968): #4      _HashMap.putIfAbsent (dart:collection-patch/collection_patch.dart:137:29)
I/flutter (14968): #5      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement._build (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1006:26)
I/flutter (14968): #6      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1019:55)
I/flutter (14968): #7      BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2258:19)
I/flutter (14968): #8      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1012:11)
I/flutter (14968): #9      RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor._createOrObtainChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:275:23)
I/flutter (14968): #10     RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1740:58)
I/flutter (14968): #11     PipelineOwner._enableMutationsToDirtySubtrees (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:797:15)
I/flutter (14968): #12     RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1740:13)
I/flutter (14968): #13     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor._createOrObtainChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:264:5)
I/flutter (14968): #14     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor.addInitialChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:348:5)
I/flutter (14968): #15     RenderSliverList.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_list.dart:78:12)
I/flutter (14968): #16     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter (14968): #17     RenderSliverPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:182:11)
I/flutter (14968): #18     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter (14968): #19     RenderViewportBase.layoutChildSequence (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:407:13)
I/flutter (14968): #20     RenderShrinkWrappingViewport._attemptLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1651:12)
I/flutter (14968): #21     RenderShrinkWrappingViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1614:20)
I/flutter (14968): #22     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter (14968): #23     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (14968): #24     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter (14968): #25     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (14968): #26     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter (14968): #27     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (14968): #28     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter (14968): #29     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (14968): #30     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter (14968): #31     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (14968): #32     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter (14968): #33     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (14968): #34     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter (14968): #35     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (14968): #36     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter (14968): #37     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (14968): #38     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter (14968): #39     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (14968): #40     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter (14968): #41     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (14968): #42     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter (14968): #43     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (14968): #44     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter (14968): #45     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (14968): #46     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter (14968): #47     RenderSliverList.performLayout.advance (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_list.dart:201:17)
I/flutter (14968): #48     RenderSliverList.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_list.dart:234:19)
I/flutter (14968): #49     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter (14968): #50     RenderSliverPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:182:11)
I/flutter (14968): #51     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter (14968): #52     RenderViewportBase.layoutChildSequence (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:407:13)
I/flutter (14968): #53     RenderViewport._attemptLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1322:12)
I/flutter (14968): #54     RenderViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1240:20)
I/flutter (14968): #55     RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1519:7)
I/flutter (14968): #56     PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:766:18)
I/flutter (14968): #57     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:347:19)
I/flutter (14968): #58     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:701:13)
I/flutter (14968): #59     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:286:5)
I/flutter (14968): #60     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1012:15)
I/flutter (14968): #61     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:952:9)
I/flutter (14968): #62     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:864:5)
I/flutter (14968): #66     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:219:10)
I/flutter (14968): #67     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:178:3)
I/flutter (14968): (elided 3 frames from package dart:async)
I/flutter (14968): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (14968): 1
I/flutter (14968): null
I/flutter (14968): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
I/flutter (14968): 2
I/flutter (14968): null
I/flutter (14968): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
```

So from terminal output , we can see its not printing `hit 7` , so something wrong with json parsing.

Comment: snapshot.data is ```null```, you can not get ```snapshot.data[index]```

Comment: @NhaPhạmThị I know its null, buy why it is null thats the main issue here.